# executeAsync failing silently when inserting records

Tags: java, cassandra

I am attempting to use the Cassandra Java driver to do a bulk insert of a large amount of records to two different tables on a cluster. I'm starting with a test data set of about 600 records (resulting in 600 records on each table), but will eventually be inserting about 2.5 million. I am using a prepared statement, and binding each record PreparedStatement and BoundStatement.

When I perform the inserts synchronously (with `session.execute`), everything behaves as expected, with all records being inserted and showing up when I do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` from cqlsh. However, if I use `session.executeAsync`, only about 90% of the records are returned in each table when I query from cqlsh. After the inserts, I am waiting on all of the futures using `ResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly`, but this has not made a difference, even if I attempt to batch the inserts in groups (e.g. call `session.executeAsync` 50 times, then call `ResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly` on those 50 before continuing).

I do not see any exceptions, and looking at `resultSet.wasApplied()` always returns true. I am using Cassandra 2.1.4, and have tried this both on a 3-node cluster on localhost, as well as a deployed 3-node cluster on AWS.

edit: I tried processing the larger dataset of 2.5 million records just to see what might happen, and after about 30,000 records, I start seeing the following message in console:

> [cluster1-timeouter-0] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.RequestHandler - onTimeout triggered but the response was completed by another thread, cancelling (retryCount = 0, queryState = QueryState(count=0, inProgress=false, cancelled=false), queryStateRef = QueryState(count=0, inProgress=false, cancelled=false))

Additionally, with the larger dataset, the longer the inserts continue, the larger the gap between processed records and successful inserts. E.g. after about 600,000 records processed, I only see about 440,000 records in Cassandra. I also tried adding a callback to each future to log any failures to console:

```
ResultSetFuture accountFuture = session.executeAsync(insertAccount(insertStmt, record));
Futures.addCallback(accountFuture, new FutureCallback<ResultSet>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(@Nullable com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet resultSet) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
        System.out.printf("Failed with: %s\n", throwable);
    }
});
```

However, I do not see any failures in console.

Comment: Is interesting to know how/if you solved

Comment: can you post the code that prepares and binds statements?

Comment: is your only measure "select count(*)" ?
have you tried to select * and counting them?
(bad memories from mysql...)

also, stupid question but is any of part you primary key involving random or time (or potentially colliding values)?

Comment: can you share complete source code. as it seems some logical mistake with code, probably code you written to generate records, might overwriting some of rows that's why count is not correct. If futures are completed, records must have been inserted in table.

Comment: This is an old post now, but doesn't have enough detail on the cluster. Please add cluster topology from `nodetool status` plus any investigation carried out on the cluster side (i.e. any errors in the logs?). Also need to include driver side `cluster` setup like Load Balancing policy, Consistency level etc